# No error with this collection declared with generics?

Tags: java, collections

I have below code snippet and this works fine. Shouldn't it throw compile time error because I have defined `c` as `ArrayList` which will contain `String` object but I am adding `Integer` object. So why it did not throw compile time/Run time error?

```
Collection c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add(123);
```

I know below will throw compile time error but why not above. Whats the logical difference between both these code snippet?

```
 Collection<String>() c = new ArrayList();
 c.add(123);
```

Comment: The first should give a `"rawtypes"` warning. Take heed of the compiler. It's a good idea to keep your code lint free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first code snippet does not result in a compile time error, because at the line

```
c.add(123)
```

the compiler inspects the type of c. Since you *declared* c as [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), the compiler treats it as such. Since `Collection` offers a method `add(Object)`, it is perfectly reasonable to `add` any object to the c, especially an integer. Note that this program *will* however result in a runtime-error, if you attempt to read back the collection values as Strings.

In your second code snippet you provide more information for the compiler to work with. In this snippet it knows that the `Collection` it deals with is an `Collection<String>`, which can only accept `Strings`. Thus, there is no method `add(int)` or `add(Object)`, only `add(String)`. This leads to a compile-time error.

Comment: The OP's first snippet will run fine; there will be no runtime error until you try to read the `Integer` as a `String`.

Comment: I'd have thought that there would be one, but according to @OliCharlesworth's comment to his own answer, it seems that it does not. I would prefer there to be one, but apparently Java doesn't think so :)

Answer (score 3):

> why it did not throw compile time error?

Because it's not syntactically or semantically invalid, it's just unwise.

Note that most modern IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) can be configured to warn you about the unparameterised `Collection c`, and optionally to fail to compile.

Comment: Well Oli it should give runtime error than becuase i have declared ArrayList which should contain String object but i am adding integer object. But it did not give any runtime error too. Why so?

Comment: @emilly: because generics don't exist at runtime; they're *erased*.  So at runtime, all collections act as if they're raw (unparameterised).

Comment: Then there is no benefit of doing new ArrayList<String>() Right? In fact declaring Collection on right handside with element type is kind of useless exception suppressing warning

Comment: @emilly: In a sense, no, there's no reason to parameterise the object, beyond the fact that it prevents (potentially useful) warning messages.  But it's still conventional to do so.

Comment: Theres tons of benefits. It provides early warning of coding bugs and saves on an obscene amount of casting that needed to be done pre Java 5. The problem here is that you are using an unparametized Collection on the lhs of your expression. Though legal, as @OliCharlesworth mentioned, its unwise.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the collection is "raw". This will usually result in a warning but not an error (depending on your exact set-up). This is primary in order to be able to compile all the pre-Java 5 legacy code around.

The the second example, you assign a "raw" object to a parameterized version, which only can be done with an explicit cast.

Comment: Ideally it should result runtime error But it did not throw that :(

Answer (score 0):

1) What is the logical difference?

Above: A Collection can be declared without a generic type. This is called a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). The collection can then hold any kind of collection. Since, with a raw typed collection, at runtime you *might* use a collection of strings as a collection of integers causing a runtime exception the compiler will usually throw a warning. Since you have not typed the collection in the above example the compiler can not prevent these runtime exceptions. The warning can be ignored if you know what it is for and know what you are doing.

Below: But a variable declared as a Collection<String> cannot hold any kind of collection. It *has to be* a collection of the type String. It is strong typed. The compiler is correct to see this as an error.

2) Why does the above snippet not cause a compiler error?

Java is [strong typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing), which ensures [type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). The above snippet is not type safe, but allowed by Java nonetheless. This is probably for historical reasons: Generics were only introduced with Java 1.5, so if the above snippet would have caused a compile error then most Java 1.4 code would have been broken in the Java 1.5 compiler.

Not every programming language evolves in such a backward compatible manner (PHP for instance). Apparently backward compatibility was valued over type safety when introducing Java 1.5.